# FileMaker Pro 13: How to get a summary variable to display an accurate total

Tags: database, boolean, field, filemaker, summary

I am working on a database of records that includes a step that only needs to be performed for some of the records (about a fourth of them). To keep track of which records needs the extra step, I created a boolean field with 0 for "doesn't need the step" and 1 for "needs the extra step" (these are assigned before importing the information into the database). There is also an option for the user to click a button and change the boolean from 0 to 1 (in case the record needs the extra step in the future).

The database also has a report feature that shows the total number of records that needs this extra step. I need this field to display the current total number of these records, so I have tried setting up a summary variable called Total PLQA that is defined to give the "Total of" and then the boolean variable (PLQA Bool). Somehow, I got the total to work once, but it seems that the reporting variable "Total PLQA" does not update when new records are added to the database or when users change the boolean value. Somehow, I need to get the variable to update whenever the report script is run and I can't figure out how to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried setting up a summary variable called Total PLQA that is
>   defined to give the "Total of"

That would be a summary **field**, not a *variable*.

> it seems that the reporting variable "Total PLQA" does not update when
>   new records are added to the database or when users change the boolean
>   value.

A summary field always displays the summary value for the current found set (unless you place it in a sub-summary part, where it will display the sub-summary value for each sorted group).

Make sure your report layout is based on the same table where the summary field is defined, and that the summary field's instance placed on the layout is coming from the same table occurrence.

Note also that:

1. After import, only the imported/updated records will be found;
2. If you modify the Boolean field, you must commit the record before you will see the summary field reflect the change.

Comment: When modifying the Boolean field, I use a button that replaces the field contents without displaying a dialog; does this count as committing the record? I just changed the report page's layout to be associated with the template matching the template with the summary field (the "Index" template), but I don't see any changes with the summary field in the report. It looks like Filemaker changed all of the instances to match the change in template, so that looks like it worked. Currently, I have 3 records in the database that need the extra step, but the summary field still only shows 1.

Comment: It is very difficult to follow your description because of your incorrect terminology - for example, FileMaker has no "templates". Also, why are you replacing the field contents - an action that affects all records in the found set - instead of setting the field in the current record only? In any case, neither will commit the record/s. Use a script (as opposed to a attaching a single script step to a button) and end it with the Commit Records step.